# Missing questions from area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, area-51, off-topic

I was looking at my proposal on area 51.   http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85/gardening-and-farming-organically   Somewhat worryingly the questions with most "great off-topic example" votes have floated to the top of the first page.  I went looking for the questions with "great on-topic example" votes and more worryingly a lot of questions seem to be missing completely.  Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the other tabs?

On ["on-topic"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top) I see "What is worm composting and how would it benefit my organic garden as opposed to regular composting?" as the top question on 24 votes, followed by ones on 18, 17 and 12 votes.

On ["off-topic"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85?tab=offtopic&phase=definition#tab-top) I see "Where is the best place in the world to garden?" on 20, followed by ones on 19, 14 and 13 votes.

Comment: Sorry - I had misunderstood the functionality.  A bit late to say this but that is an odd way to have it - "off-topic being the default.

Comment: @Ciaran - I don't think "off-topic" is the default. It just remembers the last tab you looked at.

Comment: D'oh!  Brain not working!